# What is this? '[C]: ?'

Tags: debugging, lua, stack-trace, traceback

Compile in lua, any result to output at console.

I have a one question.

> [C]: ?   <- what is that mean?

```
stack traceback:
    test2.lua:2: in function 'myfunction'
    test2.lua:8: in main chunk
    [C]: ?   <----- this point
```

Comment: For the deep details, this is related to the `debug.traceback` function and the [what](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_Debug) field of the `debug.getinfo` structure.

Answer (score 4):

It means that level of the stack traceback is in a C function (as opposed to a lua function).

For example:

```
$ lua -e 'print(io.popen())'
lua: (command line):1: bad argument #1 to 'popen' (string expected, got no value)
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'popen'
    (command line):1: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
```

vs.

```
$ lua -e 'function t() print(nil + 5) end t()'
lua: (command line):1: attempt to perform arithmetic on a nil value
stack traceback:
    (command line):1: in function 't'
    (command line):1: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
```